# Determine if zoom if vertical or horizontal

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

How would you determine in a zoomCallback function if the zoom was X-Zoom or Y-Zoom ?

The idea is to trigger a server query on X-Zoom and not on Y-Zoom.

Both the timestamp and Y range values slightly change in the 2 kind of zoom.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

The x-values shouldn't change on a y-zoom. If you can reproduce this (and I can't on [this page](http://dygraphs.com/tests/callback.html)) then please file an issue.

Comment: I found the issue, it's because I use fixed dateWindow, and when I unzoom the dateWindow changed to the data's bounds.

example: dateWindow from 2005 to 2010 and values only in 2008. On unzoom, the dateWindow will be 2008-2008. So I cannot determine if it was a Y-zoom